# What are some pre-release marketing strategies?

Tags: marketing

How can I find a good publicist to help me market my book that I want to release in November 2019?

Comment: The title of the question doesn't match the body. Which one is the question you want to ask?

Comment: Both of those are reasonable questions, though they may have been asked here before.  Please only ask one focused question per post.

Comment: Find the guy who works in marketing and likes arts and give him half minimum fixed salary paycheck + percentage of your book (~5-10%. If your book is beautiful and have good points - he will promote those lines and will sell your first publication. Second, Third, Fifth and Tenth publications will need more complex multi strategies so my point is - just invite your marketing-related friend for a coffee and ask what marketing campaigns you should do to sell 2000-10000 copies. I would do 5-10 campaigs via 2-5 channels with a medium budget. p.s. cooperation with a retailer is a must! Good luck!